# Situations where to use "Shake and bake, baby"

Tags: expressions

In which situations is appropriate to use the expression "Shake and bake, baby"?

Comment: if you're with senior citizens. Seriously, no one says this anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The origin of this term is a borrowing from a brand name of a Kraft Foods product line, [first released on the market in 1965](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shake_%27n_Bake#cite_note-2):

[image]

Almost since its inception the term has been borrowed to described tricky moves in sports, especially basketball. An example of this may be heard in the 1994 film *[The Air Up There](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Air_Up_There)*.

> In the film *The Air Up There*, Charles Gitonga Maina's character is taught "the Jimmy Dolan shake n' bake move" (fake left, fake right, between your opponent's legs) however he was not allowed to use it when he played at Lynn University because his coach would not allow it.

Its transference to the meaning of "awesome" is obvious. Putting a "shake 'n' bake" move on an opponent usually meant leaving him flat-footed while the person with the ball glides past for a score. The time to use it for yourself would be when you have done something particularly tricky or dazzling that permits you to achieve a desired goal.

Comment: Seems you put the shake'n bake on Ham'n Bac'n.

Answer (score 2):

It is used when someone has just done something really awesome or cool i.e. backflip five times on top of a fence. Example:

> A: Did you really earn $500 in that game?
>   B: Yeah.
>   A: Shake and bake, baby!